# How to enable Istio SDS on existing GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have an existing GKE cluster with the Istio addon installed, e.g.:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create istio-demo \
    --addons=Istio --istio-config=auth=MTLS_PERMISSIVE \
    --cluster-version=[cluster-version] \
    --machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
    --num-nodes=4
```

I am following [this guide](https://medium.com/@gregoire.waymel/istio-cert-manager-lets-encrypt-demystified-c1cbed011d67)  to install `cert-manager` in order to automatically provision TLS certificates from Let's Encrypt. According to the guide, Istio needs SDS enabled which can be done at the point of installation:

```
helm install istio.io/istio \
       --name istio \
       --namespace istio-system \
       --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.sds.enabled=true
```

As I already have Istio installed via GKE, how can I enable SDS on the existing cluster? Alternatively, is it possible to use the `gcloud` CLI to enable SDS at the point of cluster creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Carlos' answer, I decided not to use the `Istio on GKE` addon as there is very limited customization available when using Istio as a managed service.

I created a standard GKE cluster...

```
gcloud beta container clusters create istio-demo \
    --cluster-version=[cluster-version] \
    --machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
    --num-nodes=4
```

And then manually installed Istio...

1. Create the namespace:

```
kubectl create namespace istio-system
```

2. Install the Istio CRDs:

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init --name istio-init --namespace istio-system | kubectl apply -f -
```

3. Install Istio using the default configuration profile with my necessary customizations:

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system \
    --set gateways.enabled=true \
    --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.enabled=true \
    --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.sds.enabled=true \
    --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.externalTrafficPolicy="Local" \
    --set global.proxy.accessLogFile="/dev/stdout" \
    --set global.proxy.accessLogEncoding="TEXT" \
    --set grafana.enabled=true \
    --set kiali.enabled=true \
    --set prometheus.enabled=true \
    --set tracing.enabled=true \
  | kubectl apply -f -
```

4. Enable Istio sidecar injection on default namespace

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
```

Answer (score 3):

Managed Istio per design will revert any custom configuration and will disable SDS again. So, IMHO, it is a non-useful scenario. You can enable SDS manually following this [guide](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/), but keep in mind that the configuration will remain active only for 2-3 minutes.

Currently GKE doesn't support enabling SDS when creating a cluster from scratch. On GKE managed Istio, Google is looking to have the ability to [enable SDS on GKE clusters](https://issuetracker.google.com/139494007), but they don't have an ETA yet for that release.

However, if you use non-managed (open source) Istio, SDS feature is in the [Istio roadmap](https://istio.io/about/feature-stages/), and I think it should be available in version 1.2, but it is not a guarantee.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. This is the exact route I went down. I recreated my GKE cluster without the Istio addon and then manually installed Istio with SDS enabled. I will post a separate answer with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Even though currently the `default ingress gateway` created by `Istio on GKE` doesn't support SDS, you can add your own extra ingress gateway manually.

You can get the manifest of the default `istio-ingressgateway` `deployment` and `service` in your `istio-system` namespace and modify it to add the SDS container and change the name and then apply it to your cluster. But it's a little too tedious, there's a simpler way to do that:

First download the open-source helm chart of istio (choose a version that works with your Istio on GKE version, in my case my Istio on GKE is 1.1.3 and I downloaded open-source istio 1.1.17 and it works):

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-release/releases/1.1.17/charts/istio-1.1.17.tgz
# extract under current working directory
tar xzvf istio-1.1.17.tgz
```

Then render the helm template for only the ingressgateway component:

```
helm template istio/ --name istio \
--namespace istio-system \
-x charts/gateways/templates/deployment.yaml \
-x charts/gateways/templates/service.yaml \
--set gateways.istio-egressgateway.enabled=false \
--set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.sds.enabled=true > istio-ingressgateway.yaml
```

Then manually modify the rendered `istio-ingressgateway.yaml` file with following  modifications:

1. Change the `metadata.name` for both the deployment and service to something else like `istio-ingressgateway-sds`
2. Change the `metadata.lables.istio` for both the deployment and service to something else like `ingressgateway-sds`
3. Change the `spec.template.metadata.labels` for the deployment similarly to `ingressgateway-sds`
4. Change the `spec.selector.istio` for the service to same value like `ingressgateway-sds`

Then apply the yaml file to your GKE cluster:

```
kubectl apply -f istio-ingressgateway.yaml
```

Holla! You have your own istio ingressgatway with SDS created now and you can get the load balancer IP of it by:

```
kubectl -n istio-system get svc istio-ingressgateway-sds
```

To let your `Gateway` to use the correct sds enabled ingressgateway you need to set `spec.selector.istio` to match the one you set. Below is an example of a `Gateway` resource using a kubernetes secret as TLS cert:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway-test
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway-sds
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*.example.com'
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - hosts:
    - '*.example.com'
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: example-com-cert
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: sds
      serverCertificate: sds
```